# Read text from text file

Tags: python

My text file has 2-3 paragraphs with blank line seperating each para. I have to read all words from the text file and count the words. But the problem is it is reading the blank line and give result as '  :2'. How to remove this line while reading the file. I already used line = line.strip() , but still shows ' :2'
output shows:

the : 2

```
: 2
```

are : 1

**text file contents are:**

Google makes money by advertising. People or companies who want people to buy their product, service, or ideas give Google money, and Google shows an advertisement to people Google thinks will click on the advertisement.

Google only gets money when people click on the link, so it tries to know as much about people as possible to only show the advertisement to the right people.

This is the last line.

```
d=dict()
f = open('/Users/admin/Desktop/textfile.txt','r')
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    line=line.strip('\n')
    words = line.split(" ")
                     
    for word in words:
        if word in d:
            d[word] = d[word] + 1
        else:
            d[word] = 1

for key in list(d.keys()):
    print(key, ":", d[key])
```

Comment: Oops! Looks like you forgot to post the code, sample input and required output. Do that and someone may help you

Comment: Can you share the textfile.txt?

Comment: Please [edit] your question rather than using Drive

Comment: Sorry, It does not show the option to upload a file.

Comment: There is no upload file option, no. You can copy-paste the text of the file

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check empty lines before you count words in it

```
for line in f:
    line = line.strip()
    if line: 
       # it is not empty, so continue counting
```

Also, you can use a Counter rather than a plain dict

```
from collections import Counter 

d = Counter()
with open(...) as f:
    for line in f:
        line = line.strip()
        if line:
            words = line.split()
            d.update(Counter(words))

for key, value in d.items():
    print(f'{key}: {value}')
```

Comment: Yes ,  using Counter works. but why it didnt work work with plain dict? I tried to use if line: condition, it didnt work.

Comment: Plain dict will work fine. The counter just removes your uncessary `d[word] += 1` and `if` checks around that... Anyways, I suggest you debug more to print the line before you count the words in it. When `if line` doesn't work, that means you have a non-empty line.